# Access jQuery UI datepicker cell on beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I would like to be able to add a data attribute to a cell of a jQuery UI datepicker. I've looked into using the beforeShowDay, but it appears to only give the date. Is there an efficient way to select the table cell corresponding to that date?

Comment: I think asking *why* you need the cells to have that data attribute is an important question

Comment: I'd like a data attribute so that when I add a hover event to the cells I can grab the attribute easily. I could possibly add it to the class with some sort of delimiters around it, but that isn't ideal since it requires further processing to get the data.

Comment: What information is in the data attribute?  Why can't it be built at hover time?

Comment: It's an id corresponding to an event that occurs on that day. There are other days in the calendar that may have the same id and I need to be able to highlight all days with that corresponding id.

Comment: In that case why don't you store the dates and their events elsewhere (in a variable or some hidden list in the DOM) and then compare to that in `beforeShowDay`?

Comment: I should clarify my previous comment. I need to be able to highlight all days with the same id on hover of a particular cell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would have to use classes to do this

Comment: Yeah my current idea is to add a delimiter around the id and add it as a class because on the hover I need some way to extract the id. Then, once given the idea do a wild card search for the id extracted. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I should clarify that this is an ID associated with an event, not an actual CSS ID.